# Can I work out the numbers in the groups, based on the results of hazard ratio?

Tags: hazard, ratio

I need to extract data from a paper that report a hazard ratio=0.72,
95% CI=0.57, 0.92, p=0.010. Knowing that the one group that did better had 255 individuals and the other 252. How can I find out the concrete numbers based on the hazard ratio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have the hazard ratio with 95% CI (and possibly a p-value) from a Cox-regression, you cannot work out the number of patients. All you can work out - if you know that there was a 1:1 randomization - from the confidence interval width is the number of patients with at least one event, because you know that asyptomtically the estimate of the log-hazard rate has a variance of 4 divided the number of events and that on the log-scale the confidence interval is approximately $\log(\hat{\beta}) \pm 1.96\ldots \times \sqrt{\text{Var}(\hat{\beta})}$. This applies as long as this number is large enough for the asymptotics to apply. If other randomization ratios this is less straightforward. If you know that follow-up in the two treatment groups was very comparable and the proportion that experienced an event was very low, then the hazard ratio will be approximately the ratio of of the number with an event in each group so that those can also be approximately back-calculated.

Comment: I also have the log-rank p=0.017, but I suppose this would also not be enough to figure out the numbers right?

Comment: Correct. From that you can also back-calculate to number of events as above (the test statistic being approx. log HR / SE (log HR)).